# WebView WebClient - Force open new browser using JS

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Is there any way to force open new browser on Webview when WebClient enable using Javascript? I would like to avoid edit app code. I already tried using window.open but no success.

Here is my webView setting:-

```
Browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Browser.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
Browser.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
Browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```